# Why does my Tkinter calculator only output 0?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I have been trying to make a simple calculator in python using the Tkinter module, and all it does is display 0. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
calclabel = tk.Label(text = "This is a calculator.\nType yor numbers in the space given below and click on any on the operators to carry out the operation.")
calclabel.pack()
entry1 = tk.Entry()
entry1.pack()
entry2 = tk.Entry()
entry2.pack()
a = int()
b = int()
entry1.get = a
entry2.get = b
def addcommand () :
    addlabel = tk.Label(text = a+b)
    addlabel.pack()

def subcommand () :
    sublabel = tk.Label(text = a-b)
    sublabel.pack()

def multicommand () :
    multilabel = tk.Label(text = a*b)
    multilabel.pack()

def divicommand () :
    divilabel = tk.Label(text = a/b)
    divilabel.pack()

add = tk.Button(text = "Add",
                command = addcommand,
                master = window)
add.pack()

sub = tk.Button(text = "Substract",
                command = subcommand,
                master = window)
sub.pack()

mul = tk.Button(text = "Multiply",
                command = multicommand,
                master = window)
mul.pack()

div = tk.Button(text = "Divide",
                command = divicommand,
                master = window)
div.pack()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I think it is a logic error and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are doing it the wrong way.
Every time you perform any `command`, you should get the value from `entry` and then calculate.
Like shown below

```py
def addcommand () :
    a = int(entry1.get()) # get the value from entry1 and cast it to integer
    b = int(entry2.get()) # get the value from entry1 and cast it to integer
    addlabel = tk.Label(text = a+b) # do the calculation
    addlabel.pack()
```

You can use `try except` block during casting for handling `exception`.

Here is how you can do it

```py
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
calclabel = tk.Label(text = "This is a calculator.\nType yor numbers in the space given below and click on any on the operators to carry out the operation.")
calclabel.pack()
entry1 = tk.Entry()
entry1.pack()
entry2 = tk.Entry()
entry2.pack()
# a = int()
# b = int()
# entry1.get = a
# entry2.get = b
def addcommand () :
    a = int(entry1.get())
    b = int(entry2.get())
    addlabel = tk.Label(text = a+b)
    addlabel.pack()

def subcommand () :
    a = int(entry1.get())
    b = int(entry2.get())
    sublabel = tk.Label(text = a-b)
    sublabel.pack()

def multicommand () :
    a = int(entry1.get())
    b = int(entry2.get())
    multilabel = tk.Label(text = a*b)
    multilabel.pack()

def divicommand () :
    a = int(entry1.get())
    b = int(entry2.get())
    divilabel = tk.Label(text = a/b)
    divilabel.pack()

add = tk.Button(text = "Add",
                command = addcommand,
                master = window)
add.pack()

sub = tk.Button(text = "Substract",
                command = subcommand,
                master = window)
sub.pack()

mul = tk.Button(text = "Multiply",
                command = multicommand,
                master = window)
mul.pack()

div = tk.Button(text = "Divide",
                command = divicommand,
                master = window)
div.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe a bit more comments than just "it seems you are doing it the wrong way" could be helpful - what did you change in your answer?

Comment: Every time you call one of these commands you still create a new label. Unless the OP explicitly states he wishes to keep a log of all past calculations, it'd be better to advise that you should have a third tkinter object which you update with the result of the calculation each time.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now!

Comment: @ArjunSharma Don't forget to accept the answer ;)